# how to use a #pragma in a macro? (how to escape the '#' in a macro?)

Tags: c, macros, iar

Looking for implementing the `EXPECT_NO_CRASH` from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57312559/what-is-the-inverse-of-expect-death/57324551#57324551) directly in embedded software with an UART com ongoing on a terminal.

**The purpose is just simple:**

If the function call works ok, the "OK" is printed, if the program crashes, nothing is displayed on the terminal.

**How did I implemented it?**

```
 #define CALL_DID_NOT_CRASH do{ function; printf("Function call to "#function" did not crash : OK \n",NULL); }while(0)
```

**How to use it?**

`CALL_DID_NOT_CRASH(myFunction(1,2,3));`

returns if call is ok:

> Function call to myFunction(1,2,3) did not crash : OK

otherwise return nothing, system is stopped/frozen, or reset.

The only problem I have is this warning:

> Warning[Pe225]: the format string ends before this argument

I know why, it is because there is two ')' in the macro call and because of the first comma ',' which ends the macro argument:

```
CALL_DID_NOT_CRASH(myFunction(1,2,3));
-------------------------------^---^^
```

But I don't care because **it works**.

I'm using IAR 8.20.2, how to get rid of this warning but only for each call of this macro?
I was thinking of a #pragma...but the '#' bothers me...

```
#define CALL_DID_NOT_CRASH do{ #pragma warning disable Pe225 function; printf("Function call to "#function" did not crash : OK \n",NULL); #pragma warning restore Pe225 }while(0)
```

> Error[Pe020]: identifier "pragma" is undefined

Comment: TL;DR of dupe: Use `_Pragma`, replacing `#pragma warning disable/enable Pe225` with `_Pragma("warning disable/enable Pe225")`

Comment: You say that you don't care about the warning, but your understanding of why the warning is happening is wrong, and it's easy to fix.  Change `printf("Function call to "#function" did not crash : OK \n",NULL);` to `printf("Function call to %s did not crash: OK\n", #function);` and the warning should go away.

Comment: it's not working:```#pragma warning disable Pe225``` ---> ```Warning[Pe161]: unrecognized #pragma ```

Comment: thanx zwol you saved my life